# I Format new hard drive but the result cannot read by my PC

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I use **Gparted** 
the result if we use disk as follow

[image]

the result is partition unknown...
How to use my new Hard Drive

Comment: You did not set a partition type, make the table dos and the filesystem fat32

Comment: If you are using UEFI or will use UEFI, better to set label/type to gpt. FAT32 only recommended for smaller partitions as it does not have journal and cannot store files over 4GB. With gparted: Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting.

Comment: I select mkfs.ext4...It's take long time to finish..maybe take 10 hours

Comment: dude, you have also unallocated space on that drive

Comment: I type Fdisk -l the result is:Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x940988a0

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          202752  836306943  836104192 398.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       836306944 3907024895 3070717952   1.4T  6 FAT16

Comment: type 83 Linux...and Disklabel type:dos

Answer (score 0):

Your partition table on this drive is incorrect.

And... creating a new partition should only take a minute or two. Something is wrong.

Start over...

- start `gparted`
- select the proper drive from the pop up
- go to the `Device` menu and choose `Create Partition Table`
- choose `gpt` partition table
- click the `Apply` icon (this will wipe the drive)
- then create new partition(s)

  - use `ext4` if this is to be used exclusively in Ubuntu
  - use `ntfs` if this is to be used to share files with Windows

Comment: but Gparted scanning my external in very long time...it is look like Gparted never finish scanning...

Comment: @JunusTirtasurja at what point is gparted "scanning"? When first starting gparted, or at a later step in my procedure? Do you have Windows installed. Is this a new drive? Is it plugged into a USB 2 or USB 3 port? Does the drive enclosure have its own external power supply?

Comment: I  run sudo dmesg | tail
[ 8902.292447] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 8902.292455] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Record not found
[ 8902.292464] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 02 00 00 06 00
[ 8902.292470] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdc, sector 3907028994

Comment: It's look like my external HD 4 TB?...not 2 TB

Comment: my drive take power from USB...the catalog said it's usb 3...but I use ol laptop...

Comment: If it's really that large a drive, it must have its own AC power adapter, yes? Are you using it?

Comment: I use window 7 DiskPart the Result :DISKPART> FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="NEW HD" QUICK

   0 percent completed

DiskPart has ecountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information

Comment: Sorry, we had a three day power outage here. You didn't answer my question about the AC power adapter for the external disk drive enclosure. Try `gparted` to lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the drive) then create a NTFS partition(s) at the sizes you desire.